# Laravel Sail can not use composer on Docker conrainer

Tags: laravel, docker, containers

I am trying to work on Laravel Bootcamp to learn Laravel. I am trying to use composer require in container but it gives an error at screenshot below:

[image: cli error]

I can not find any solution because sail should provide me docker-compose.yml file so i don't need to do configuration. Can you help me about this issue?

I tried to restart docker container but it didn't work.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "*",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Here is my composer.json file.

EDIT: Still could not find any solution. I'm new to laravel and Docker and i'm following the laravel bootcamp https://bootcamp.laravel.com/inertia/installation#installation-via-docker as a documentation. Here is my Docker Desktop:

[image: docker desktop]

As you can see everything looks fine and when i go to http://localhost laravel project is working. But i realized something in my docker:

[image: docker desktop images section]

Images section on my docker desktop, laravelsail/php82-composer is unused and not in my working container. I think this causes my problem. I cannot use this image somehow.

[image: error trying to install laravel/breeze on my project]

I got an error like this when i am trying to install something with composer. That's all from me and i'm really exhausted with this problem. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as an operating system not a virtual system. Please help me!! I'm begging you :)

EDIT: The problem was fixed thanks to @matiaslauriti. You can check out on comments section.

Comment: you work with wsl?

Comment: @yossi nope, i am using ubuntu 22.04 as an operating system in my computer

Comment: You have something wrong on your `composer.json`, share it please, and also try deleting the `vendor` folder and doing it again

Comment: have you tried composer update and self-update?

Comment: did you try running **sudo composer install**, this may occur due to a permission issue.

Comment: @matiaslauriti when i delete the vendor file and try to use command it says: ``` sh: 0: cannot open vendor/bin/sail: No such file```

Comment: @charindu i am already running in docker container so i shouldnt need to install locally or am i wrong?

Comment: @yossi still not working composer update

Comment: oh, I forgot that sail is inside it, my bad, run `composer install` again

Comment: @matiaslauriti man, i updated the post, i think i'm struggling with docker images, but i can not find any solution. Can you check the last screenshots pls?

Comment: So, you have to do this, go to the project, where you have the `docker-compose.yml` or `.yaml` file, and run `docker compose up -d` (if it says something about `docker compose`, use `docker-compose`), that will start all the stuff in the background. Then run `docker compose exec laravel.test bash`, that will let you go inside the PHP container, and execute any `composer` whatever command, so you can install or require whatever you need. If you still have issues, execute this only once: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects then follow docs

Comment: @matiaslauriti can i also execute artisan commands as well?

Comment: @matiaslauriti you' re the best man. It finally works!! Thanks, but i have one question all these problems i have struggled is because of the permission issues? If it is about the permisson issues can i give a permission access to /var/www/html with commands on docker container??

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem was, the folder that you are sharing with Docker should have your WSL user and group, if it does not, run `sudo chmod YOUR_USER:YOUR_GROUP . -R` so it is recursive